# Shadows appear inside uiimageview

Tags: swift

I am designing the asets to the app in Sketch. I want to use Shadows, and quite a lot of spread. However, the problem is that when I am exporting the assets into my iOS project in Xcode the image view needs to be a lot larger in order for the shadows to exsists.

The problem is that I'm working with a collection view and that means that there is a huge spacing in-between the cells.

Any idea how this could be solved?

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of result you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take your image without shadow and apply shadow using code. you can add shadow to `UIIamgeView`.

```
<imageview>.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.tabGrayColor.cgColor
<imageview>.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
<imageview>.layer.shadowRadius = 5
<imageview>.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
<imageview>.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

You can play around `shadowRadius` to get desired spread.

Comment: but doesn't that also increase the size of the image. I tried for some days ago and it didn't work. Could you maybe show me an image?

Comment: Thanks! Tried again and it worked. I fortgot to set masktobounds to false.

Comment: Just a follow up question. Now when I try to implant the thing that you said, I noticed that the shadow is clipped by the collection view instead, because where the cell ends does also the collection view end. tried to the its masktobounds but nothing happened? Thanks for your time!